# .NET MAUI AddDbContext with Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, maui

I have an application in .Net MAUI and I would like to know if through dependency injection, I could do the services.AddDbContext somehow. I hope to be clear

My code:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructureServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    services.AddDbContext<StoreCustomersContext>(opt =>
    {
        connectionString = configurations.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    });
}
```

Error:

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Status Deleted
     Error CS1061 "IServiceCollection" does not contain a definition for "AddDbContext" or an accessible extension method "AddDbContext" that accepts a first argument of type "IServiceCollection" (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/data-cloud/database-sqlite?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: You can refer to the official documentation:
[DbContext in dependency injection for ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#dbcontext-in-dependency-injection-for-aspnet-core). It explains how to use dependency injection configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing a package reference, such as Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer if you are using SQL Server.
Also, you need to especify the namespace in that file, wich should be Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection